# How can i navigate one xaml page to another?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

i have 2 page i need to navigate mainpage.xaml to login.page xaml but it throws me 
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** in  Root.Children.Clear();....

i added this codes in App.xaml:

```
   private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid myGrid = new Grid();
            myGrid.Children.Add(new MainPage());
            this.RootVisual = myGrid;
       }
```

and than i adde some codes on main.xaml to navigate to LoginUI.xaml

```
namespace Gen.CallCenter.UI
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Grid Root = ((Grid)(this.Parent));
            Root.Children.Clear();
            Root.Children.Add(new LoginUI());
        }
    }
}
```

How can i navigate main.xaml to LoginUI.xaml ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like [AnthonyWJones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709274/how-can-i-navigate-one-xaml-page-to-another/2709561#2709561) said you need to use the navigation framework.

First you'll need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Navigation` in your project and refernce it in you MainPage.xaml

```
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
```

Then you'll need a frame within where you'll switch different XAML pages. Something like this:

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="navFrame" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Source=”/Views/First.xaml” />
```

Now somewhere in MainPage.xaml you could have a Button with a tag

`<Button Click="Button_Click" Tag="/Views/Second.xaml" Content="Second" />`

and in the `Button_Click` eventhandler you could switch out the content showed in `navFrame`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button theButton = sender as Button;
    string url = theButton.Tag.ToString();

    this.navFrame.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

A cool thing to note is that by using NavigationFramework the browser back and forward buttons work perfectly and the URL in the addressbar updates depending on the XAML page you are currently on :)

Answer (score 13):

Let's suppose you are viewing the `MainPage.xaml` then you want to open another xaml page called `newPage.xaml` by clicking on a `Button` or an `ImageEdit` in the `MainPage.xaml`, here's the quick solution that you should write inside the `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
private void imageEdit1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    newPage mynewPage = new newPage(); //newPage is the name of the newPage.xaml file
    this.Content = mynewPage;
}
```

This is working with me.

Comment: Working for me too...if you already have the  `private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` for button control,  then don't copy the first line, other than that works perfect and easy.

Comment: Though it's been working, the URL doesn't seems to be changing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've started off on the wrong foot.  This sort of thing is catered for using the Navigation application template.  You should start a new project and select "Silverlight Navigation Application".

Once loaded just run it to see what the basic shell looks like.  Then take a look at how MainPage is structured and say the Home view.  What you will need to do is create new views based on the navigation `Page` type and then add them to MainPage.xaml.

Answer (score 2):

The simple one to solve this problem, you can look at this website : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eladkatz/archive/2011/01/25/adapting-silverlight-navigation-to-mvvm.aspx .

I had this problem to earlier. But after I read this tutorial, I can easily navigating to another view with MVVM. Hope this can help you all solve the problem.Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
private void formcombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ComboBoxItem child in formcombobox.Items)
    {
        if (child.Name != null && child.IsSelected == true)
        {

            string url = new System.Uri("/DWRWefForm;component/Pages/"
                            + child.Name + ".xaml", System.UriKind.Relative).ToString();
            this.navframe.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative)); 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void imageEdit1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    newPage mynewPage = new newPage(); //newPage is the name of the newPage.xaml file
    this.Content = mynewPage;
}
```

It's working for me. :)