# How to navigate from a usercontrol to a page

Tags: c#, xaml, uap

I have a usercontrol.When I click on a button in this usercontrol,I need to navigate to another xaml page.How can I do it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709274/how-can-i-navigate-one-xaml-page-to-another

Comment: This is UAP and need navigation from usercontrol to page.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your usercontrol.

```
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Name="ContentFrame" />
```

once the user performs a button click action c# code event function will be triggered. In that function use this to goto the page you like

```
    Page page = new Page()
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { this.ContentFrame.Navigate(page); });
```